Specific Item Order with Flexbox or Grid
I'm trying to order items in a specific order for 2 different views. I'm using Vuetify for this.
First we have a mobile view, which is very simple. I'm developing my web app with the mobile-first principle:
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| +-----------------------------------------------------+ |
| |                          1                          | |
| +-----------------------------------------------------+ |
| +-----------------------------------------------------+ |
| |                          2                          | |
| +-----------------------------------------------------+ |
| +-----------------------------------------------------+ |
| |                          3                          | |
| +-----------------------------------------------------+ |
| +-----------------------------------------------------+ |
| |                          4                          | |
| +-----------------------------------------------------+ |
| +-----------------------------------------------------+ |
| |                          5                          | |
| +-----------------------------------------------------+ |
| +-----------------------------------------------------+ |
| |                          6                          | |
| +-----------------------------------------------------+ |
+---------------------------------------------------------+

Next would be a medium viewport view for bigger screens:
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| +-------------------------+ +-------------------------+ |
| |            1            | |            6            | |
| +-------------------------+ +-------------------------+ |
| +-------------------------+                             |
| |            2            |                             |
| +-------------------------+                             |
| +-------------------------+                             |
| |            3            |                             |
| +-------------------------+                             |
| +-------------------------+                             |
| |            4            |                             |
| +-------------------------+                             |
| +-------------------------+                             |
| |            5            |                             |
| +-------------------------+                             |
+---------------------------------------------------------+

I tried some things out with flex and grid but couldn't find a good and simple solution.

UPDATE: Now I really feel dumb to only find this simple solution now. Basically I was able to solve this with a grid. The first 5 items I've included in a <VCol> and the 6th item alone in a <VCol>.
<template>
  <VRow>
    <VCol
      cols="12"
      md="6"
    >
      <div>item 1</div>
      <div>item 2</div>
      <div>item 3</div>
      <div>item 4</div>
      <div>item 5</div>
    </VCol>
    <VCol
      cols="12"
      md="6"
    >
      <div>item 6</div>
    </VCol>
  </VRow>
</template>

I would appreciate feedback, if someone knows a more elegant solution
